# Powershell command to get all the Language Packs installed on a server running windows server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I find all the language packs that are installed on my server (windows server 2012) through powershell command? 
I like to identify(through script) if any of the languages that are required by my services are not installed and then run DISM to add missing language packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse DISM output:

```
$LangPacks = DISM.exe /Online /Get-Intl /English |
    Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Installed language(s)'|
        ForEach-Object {
            if($_ -match ':\s*(.*)'){$Matches[1]}
        }

if($LangPacks -notcontains 'ru-Ru'){
    Write-Host 'Language pack not installed!'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to see this by querying WMI, the **MUILanguages** property in **Win32_OperatingSystem** I believe shows the installed languages:

```
$OSInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$languagePacks = $OSInfo.MUILanguages
$languagePacks
```

Answer (score 3):

Added Trim(), required for contains/ notcontains

```
$languagePacks = (dism /online /Get-Intl)  | 
   ?{ $_.Contains("Installed language(s):") } | 
    %{ $_.Split(":")[1].Trim() } 

if( $languagePacks -contains $language) {
  Write-host 'installed'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(dism /online /Get-Intl)  | 
    ?{ $_.Contains("Installed language(s):") } | 
    %{ $_.Split(":")[1] }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.